# Angle between Hours and minutes hand

Tags: python

I want to give hours and minutes as input with input() to find out the angle between them. I tried it but unable to execute the code.

I explicitly want to use input().I have use int(), map() with input() but it didn't work.
Here is my code:-

```
# Input hours and minutes

input_time = (input("Enter hrs,mins : ").split())
   
def cal_angle(h, m):
 if (h < 0 or m < 0 or h > 12 or m > 60):
    print("wrong input")
 if (h==12):
    h=0 
 if (m==60):
    m=0
    h=+1 
  if (h>12):
    h=h-12;

  hrs_angle = 0.5*(h*60 + m)
  min_angle = 6*m 

  #find difference between two angles
  angle = abs(hrs_angle - min_angle)

  # return smaller angle from two possible angle
  angle = (360 - angle, angle)

  return angle

print('Angle', cal_angle(h, m))
```

Comment: Please provide an example output of your code when you run it

Comment: `cal_angle(int(input_time[0]), int(input_time[1]))`?

Comment: @Tamir: It giving me error: NameError: name 'h' is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
h,m = [int(t) for t in input("Enter hrs,mins : ").split()]
```

and there are some other issues with your code:

- checking for 'wrong' hours, but then converting if (h>12): h=h-12; maybe 'wrong' is > 24 ?
- (360 - angle, angle) - this is a tuple, not the smaller of the two

Comment: I made changes you said. thereafter it gives me an error, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ',' . earlier also I used int() and it gave me the same error.

Comment: split() by default splits words separated with empty spaces.
Make it split(',') if there is a comma in the input.